# Indent every child of a depth first search (ruby on rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, depth-first-search, text-indent

I am new to rails, and I was wondering if there was a simple (or not simple) way to indent every child of a DPS?

I have a model called "Comment" that has_many :comments and belongs_to :comment. In my view I've implemented a DPS to display each comment and each comment on that comment, and each comment on that comment, etc.

My code looks like this:

```html
<div class=feed>
 <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% if comment.comment_id == nil # display all original comments %> 
   
   <!-- subject -->
   <div class="subject">
    <%= comment.subject %>:
   </div>

   <!-- create array of replies -->
   <% replies = Array.new %> 
   <% replies.push(comment) %>
   <% while replies.any? %>

    <% reply = replies[0] %>
    <% replies.delete_at(0) %>
    

    <!--- name -->
    <div class="comment">
     <%= User.find(reply.user_id).name %>
    <!-- comment -->
     <%= reply.body %>
     <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= link_to "reply", new_comment_comment_path(reply.id) %> 
     <% end %>
    </div>

    <% reply.comments.each do |further_replies| %>
     <% replies.push(further_replies) %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
   <% end %>
   <br>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

where I push each comment onto "replies" and visit each reply one by one.

Is there a good way to indent each child comment?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you draw a wireframe to understand your views?

Comment: I'm describing an indented thread like on reddit (and now facebook)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [act_as_tree](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree) structure, in that case your model will be like -

```
class Comment
   has_many :replies, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key :comment_id
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Your html code will be very simple in that case like

```
<div class=feed>
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="subject">
      <%= comment.subject %>:
    </div>
    <% comment.replies.each do |reply| %>   
      <div class="comment">
        <%= reply.user..name %>
        <%= reply.body %>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <%= link_to "reply", new_comment_comment_path(reply.id) %>    
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <br>
     <% end %>
    <br>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That's a great idea. I implemented it (and added a line in the Comment model "acts_as_tree order: 'created_at'". But I am still getting a syntax error at "has_many :replies, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key :comment_id"....

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a different approach that worked well. I implemented a recursive depth first search in "CommentsController" that returned a hash of { comments => amount_to_indent }, where comments are in the order that they were visited. In the view file iterated though the hash, using comment and amount_of_indent where appropriate.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @comments = Comment.all

  # depth first search
  @visited = Hash.new
  @comments.each do |comment|
    if !comment.comment_id        # has not parent comment
      indent = 0
      comment_array = DFS(comment, @visited, indent)
    end
  end
end

def DFS(comment, visited, indent)
  visited[comment] = indent        # add elements in order in which they are   visited
  comment.comments.each do |reply|
      DFS(reply, visited, indent + 4)
  end
  visited
end
```

And in the view file:

```html
<div class="feed">
 <% @visited.each do |reply, indent| %>
  <!-- display subject of all parent comments -->
  <div class="subject">
   <% if !reply.comment_id? %> 
    <%= reply.subject  %>:
   <% end %>
  </div>

  <!--- name and content -->
  <div class="comment">
   <!-- preceed comment with indent -->
   <%= raw(('&nbsp') * indent) %>
   <%= User.find(reply.user_id).name + ":" + reply.body %>

   <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to "reply", new_comment_comment_path(reply.id) %> 
    <!--%= link_to 'delete', response, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %-->
   <% end %>

  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

If anyone runs into the same issue I did!